# How to go about Formatting various date strings types into one preffereable format - python

Tags: python, date, datetime, format

So for example I am given Strings such as:
`1/2/12` or 
`12/03/14` or 
`7/3/2015` or 
`07/05/05`.

Note: I do not know what format the string will be in because the dates are being collected from excel files. How can I  format it to `yyyy/dd/mm` or similar to `2000/09/03`

The other post about this subject do not accommodate everything I'm looking for

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/ might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The dateutil library works pretty well